# Why memory is new when doing std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> src{1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << "src: ";
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = src.begin(); x != src.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;
    }   

    std::vector<int> dest(std::move(src));

    std::cout << "src: ";                                                       
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = src.begin(); x != src.end(); ++ x)
    {
         std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;;
    }   
    std::cout << "\ndest: ";
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = dest.begin(); x != dest.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;;
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
}

src: 1 0x43ea7d0
2 0x43ea7d4
3 0x43ea7d8
src: 
dest: 1 0x43ea7d0
2 0x43ea7d4
3 0x43ea7d8
```

This make sense because the memory address of dest is now what previously src was.

But when I do:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> src{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> dest(src.size());

    std::cout << "src: " << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = src.begin(); x != src.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;
    }   
    std::cout << "\ndest: " << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = dest.begin(); x != dest.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;
    }    
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::move_backward(src.begin() , src.end(), dest.end());

    std::cout << "src: " << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = src.begin(); x != src.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;
    }   
    std::cout << "\ndest: " << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator x = dest.begin(); x != dest.end(); ++ x)
    {
        std::cout << *x << ' ' << &(*x) << std::endl ;
    }    
    std::cout << '\n';
}

   src: 
1 0x41e0140
2 0x41e0144
3 0x41e0148

dest: 
0 0x41e0160
0 0x41e0164
0 0x41e0168

src: 
1 0x41e0140
2 0x41e0144
3 0x41e0148

dest: 
1 0x41e0160
2 0x41e0164
3 0x41e0168
```

Why is the second case the address being different? I thought std::move only changing the pointer, without touching the memory of the original object

Comment: `move_backward` is moving the *items* in the range specified by the iterators, not the range's container itself. Try it with a range with movable items.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward See at possible implementation section, and you will see that it is moving the element itself, not the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code example moves the vector itself. This moves the content of the source vector to the target vector, not touching the contained elements.

Your second code example creates a new vector of the same size as the source (with default constructed elements), and then move assigns to those elements.

This becomes apparent when you use a element type that tells you what is done with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct Thing {
    Thing() {}
    Thing & operator=(Thing &&) { std::cout << "Moved a thing" << std::endl; }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Thing> source1(1);
    std::vector<Thing> source2(1);

    std::cout << "Move vector:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Thing> vector_moved{std::move(source1)};

    std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Move elements:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Thing> elements_moved{source2.size()};
    std::move_backward(source2.begin() , source2.end(), elements_moved.end());

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/ZCWSyk):

```
Move vector:
-------------
Move elements:
Moved a thing
```